# HTML5 iPad Keyboard shows grey "Return" button instead of blue "Öffnen" (Open) button

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad

I have a web application in *HTML5* which contains a simple login page with two input fields. One holds the *type text*, the other one the *type password*.

When I tab into the password input field the *iPad* keyboard pops up and shows a grey <kbd>Return</kbd> button.

If I visit *amazon.de* on the same *Safari* page and log in hitting the password input field this button changed into a blue <kbd>Öffnen" (Open)</kbd> button.

I would like to have this blue button but I could not find a solution. Hope someone could help me out.

Thanks,
MrThrasher

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who has the same problem than me. The solution is to use the <kbd>form</kbd> element. In this case the blue button will be shown.